# Using SQL to identify periods of time with start and end dates

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I am preparing some data for a research project, and am having trouble with the following challenge.  If possible, I would like to do everything with SQL or PL SQL (although I am a true novice with PL).

Suppose we have the following table (note that Period_ID is the desired row I am trying to create):

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| Row # | Person_ID |     Code     |     Date     | Period_ID |
+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|     1 |         1 | Start_period | Jan 1st      |         1 |
|     2 |         1 | End_period   | Jan 15th     |         1 |
|     3 |         1 | Random_code1 | Feb 15th     |         1 |
|     4 |         1 | Random_code2 | Feb 28th     |         1 |
|     5 |         1 | End_period   | March 31st   |         1 |
|     6 |         1 | Start_period | May 31st     |         2 |
|     7 |         1 | End_period   | June 11th    |         2 |
|     8 |         1 | End_period   | October 28th |         2 |
+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

The columns and the challenge:

- **Person_ID**:  The above data is all for one individual (that data is at the transaction level).
- **Code**: This code can be a Start_period, End_period, or any random code.  Each Start_period code should have a corresponding End_period code. **The challenge of this problem is to identify all the Start/End pairs to create the Period_ID column.**  One importance nuance of this challenge:  the End_period code is **INVALID** if it is within 28 days of the Start_period code.  For example, the End_period code in Row 2 is invalid because it is on Jan 15th, only 14 days after Jan 1st.  Instead, the valid End_period code is on Row 5, because it is more than 28 days later.
- **Date**: Date of the transaction
- **Period_ID**:  The desired row -- this information is not currently on the table.

Comment: This seems to be a gaps and islands problem. The site already has several questions on such topics for Oracle. Perhaps one of their answers can help you? [Check them out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+gaps-and-islands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer using the always interesting Match_Recognize. Note that you shouldn't actually name columns 'Code' or 'Date', since they're reserved keywords.

Match_Recognize operates over multiple rows, and tries to match a given pattern. In your case, you're trying to match a pattern of a start code, followed by zero or more invalid end codes/other codes, followed by a valid end code.

```
WITH test_vals AS (
    SELECT 1 as person_ID,'Start_period' as my_code,to_date('Jan 1','mon dd') as my_date FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'End_period',to_date('Jan 15','mon dd') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Random_code1',to_date('Feb 15','mon dd') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Random_code2',to_date('Feb 28','mon dd') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'End_period',to_date('March 31','mon dd') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Start_period',to_date('May 31','mon dd') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'End_period',to_date('June 11','mon dd') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 1,'End_period',to_date('October 28','mon dd') FROM DUAL
)

SELECT m.person_id,
       m.my_code,
       m.my_date,
       m.period_id
FROM test_vals t
match_recognize(
    PARTITION BY person_id
    ORDER BY my_date
    MEASURES
        match_number() AS period_id /* Return the match number as the period ID */
    ALL ROWS PER match
    pattern (
        start_code /* Match a single start code */
        (invalid_end_code | other_code)* /* Match zero or more invalid end codes or other codes */
        valid_end_code /* Match a single end code */
    )
    define
        start_code AS my_code = 'Start_period', /* Start codes are always valid */
        valid_end_code AS my_code = 'End_period' AND (my_date - FIRST(my_date)) > 28, /* End codes are only valid if they come more than 28 days after the start of the pattern match */
        invalid_end_code AS my_code = 'End_period' AND (my_date - FIRST(my_date)) <= 28,
        other_code AS my_code NOT IN ('Start_period', 'End_period')
) m
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the number of start periods up through each row:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when code = 'Start_period' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by person_id order by date) as period_id
from t;
```

This works for the data you have presented.  It does not formally incorporate other rules like the timing between end periods.

Comment: Why you wrote "Just count" but use "sum"? Use count function instead.

Comment: @akk0rd87 . . . The `sum()` is doing a count.  Actually, `count(*)` isn't really necessary; it is just `sum(1)`.  If Oracle supported the standard syntax, then I would use `count(*) filter (where code = 'Start_period') . . . `.

Comment: Who is talking about "count(*)" ? I said about "count(case ... end)" or "count(decode(...))".

Answer (score 0):

I would use recursive cte, like here:

```
with c(row_, code, date_, st_date, period, chg) as (
    select row_, code, date_, date_, 1, 0 from t where row_ = 1
    union all
    select t.row_, t.code, t.date_, 
           case when chg = 1 then t.date_ else st_date end, 
           case when chg = 1 then period + 1 else period end, 
           case when t.code = 'End_period' and t.date_ - c.st_date > 28 then 1 else 0 end
      from t join c on t.row_ = c.row_ + 1
    )
select row_, code, date_, period from c
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7091a90949dddfdf580a5738588bcaed)</sup>**

The logic is to use column `chg` which steers period change. `Chg` is set to 1 when code is `End period` and date greater than previously remembered start date. In next step period is incremented, `chg` reset to zero and new starting date set.